# MSBuild setup for oracle database project in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am trying out the new oracle database project type(beta) available with VS 2015. I don't see any straightforward way to integrate with MSBuild. Is there a possibility of integrating with MSBuild?

Comment: I checked my vs2015, there isn't oracle database project. Did you install plug-in?

Comment: They are available as part of oracle developer tools (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html)

Comment: I installed it and create a new oracle database project, it could be build. So, What's the detail of your requirement?

Comment: Is the build happening as a part of the overall solution? Assume we have multiple projects in the solution, I don't see the output of this project when I build the solution. Even the .sln file does not have build definition for the project.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't build it in my VS2015, and I couldn't enable the build option in the configuration manager even if I didn't have the oracle connection during the wizard. Do you connect to the real Oracle database in that wizard? If it still has this issue, it would have a limitation. But the Oracle Database Project version 2(BETA) apps build normally.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I connected to an oracle instance and still could not build

Comment: I have vote this feedback here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3959295

Comment: @SharathChandra Which project template you used? Oracle Database project or Oracle Database Project Version 2 (BETA)? I can build Oracle Database Project Version 2 (BETA) project directly (right click that project and build), can't build it through solution build.

Comment: @s09, I am using the beta project. Yes I am able to build on the project and not on solution or via Msbuild

Comment: @JackZhai, thanks. Its been a few days since I posted the question there. The forum does not look to be active.

Comment: @SharathChandra I can't build that project via msbuild too, you need to wait its update to support build via msbuild.